# extract tar archive to existing directory in git-bash

Tags: tar, git

I have a Drupal 8 installation in a directory called `my-D8`. I want to update it to drupal 8.3.1, and I've downloaded `drupal-8.3.1.tar.gz`. I have both in my `sites` directory:

```
/d/sites $ ls
drupal-8.3.1.tar.gz  my-d8/
```

When I try to extract the archive, it puts everything in a directory called `drupal-8.3.1`, which I expected. However, I want all the files and subdirectories of that directory to overwrite (and add to) the existing `my-d8` directory.

I tried the `mv` command, but in my shell, it refused to overwrite existing non-empty subdirectories.

```
$ mv drupal-8.3.1/* my-d8/
mv: cannot move 'drupal-8.3.1/core' to 'my-d8/core': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'drupal-8.3.1/modules' to 'my-d8/modules': Directory not empty
...
```

Googling around, I found this [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/470266/88917), but when I tried it, it didn't quite to the trick:

```
$ tar -xvf  drupal-8.3.1.tar.gz --directory=my-d8  --strip-components=1
drupal-8.3.1/.csslintrc
drupal-8.3.1/.editorconfig
drupal-8.3.1/.eslintignore
... ^C
```

Instead of overwriting files in the repo's root, it simply put the subdirectory in the repo:

```
$ ls my-d8/drupal-8.3.1/
autoload.php  composer.json  composer.lock  core/  README.txt
```

**Edit** I tried dope-ghoti's answer, and upon close examination, it didn't work:

```
$ ls
drupal-8.3.1.tar.gz  my-D8/

$ tar -zx -f drupal-8.3.1.tar.gz -C my-D8

$ ls my-D8/drupal-8.3.1/
autoload.php  composer.json  ...

$ cd my-D8/

$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        drupal-8.3.1/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

How can I easily extract the archive files and directories into their respective places in my repository?

```
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.29
```

Comment: `tar -C` will set the directory into which to perform the extraction operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual:

```
 -C DIR
       change to directory DIR
```

This alters the working directory of the `tar` process.  You can also use `--strip` to remove the first component of the filenames (e. g. `drupal-8.3.1/`) in the archive.  So, you can:

```
tar --strip=1 -zx -f drupal-8.3.1.tar.gz -C my-d8
```

If your `tar` doesn't have `--strip`, it should at least have `--transform`:

```
tar --transform 's_drupal-8.3.1/__' -zx -f drupal-8.3.1.tar.gz -C my-d8
```

Comment: Right back atcha - `--strip` seems to be the missing link here.